# What are some unstable classifiers?

Tags: classification, variance-stabilizing

In my understanding, classifiers that tend to overfit (high variance) are unstable. Two examples would be unpruned decision trees and k-Nearest Neighbors with small k. Can you suggest some more classifiers like this that would have high variance?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323131/what-base-classifiers-to-use-with-bagging/323146#323146

Comment: Classifiers based on Neural Nets are unstable too.